# another jquery validation - birthdate must be between 18 and 120

Tags: jquery, validation

I have seen some examples where the `birthdate` is broken into month, day, and year. Without breaking it up, how can i run a validation for a `birthdate` field?

```
<input type="text" name="birthdate" id="birthdate"/>
```

currently, i only have:

```
birthday:  {
    required:true,
    date:true
},
```

I tried doing an ajax call on required with a function but failed to display a result based on what the other page outputs. (i.e > you must be older than 18 years old)

Comment: what format are they entering the date? (typ. US) MM/DD/YYYY? (typ. ISO) YYYY-MM-DD?